# Vertica timestamps and daylight savings time

Tags: sql, jdbc, timestamp, vertica

I'm having a very strange issue in Vertica that is related to daylight savings time.

When querying a table that stores timestamps as TIMESTAMP(6) WITHOUT TIME ZONE, the time returned as a timestamp and the time returned as converted to a varchar are one hour off each other, for times that would be impacted by daylight savings time. The timestamp return is an hour off where it should be; converting the timestamp to varchar yields the correct result.

Example:

```
-- query
select time_, time_::varchar
from <table_name>
where time_ = '2016-03-13 02:38:01.914999'

-- result
timestamp:                      converted to varchar:
'2016-03-13 03:38:01.914999'    '2016-03-13 02:38:01.914999'
              |                               |
              |                               |
              v                               v
        this is wrong           this is the desired behavior
```

To make matters weirder, when the output is ordered by time, the timestamp is treated correctly by Vertica:

```
-- query
select t.time_, t.time_::varchar
from <table_name> t
where t.time_ >= '2016-03-13 00:30:00'
  and t.time_ <  '2016-03-13 04:00:00'
order by t.time_

-- result
timestamp:                   converted to varchar:
'2016-03-13 00:31:25.087'    '2016-03-13 00:31:25.087'  ---> ok
'2016-03-13 00:31:32.236'    '2016-03-13 00:31:32.236'  ---> ok
'2016-03-13 03:38:02.042'    '2016-03-13 02:38:02.042'  ---> do not match
'2016-03-13 03:18:28.332'    '2016-03-13 03:18:28.332'  ---> ok
```

I'm running Vertica using this Docker image (https://hub.docker.com/r/sumitchawla/vertica/), and connecting via a JDBC driver. This problem is application agnostic - it occurs when the data is queried from both SQuirreL and MATLAB. I've also confirmed the Vertica instance has its timezone set to UTC:

```
-- query
show timezone

-- result
name:         setting:
'timezone'    'UTC'
```

How can I get the desired behavior? To be clear, I would like 'select time_' to return what 'select time_::varchar' returns.

Thank you!

---

Update: based on the very helpful feedback from @mauro and @woot, it appears that this may be a known bug with the Vertica JDBC driver release 7.1.2-0, and it's possible that there may be a fix in a later release (7.1.2-17; see https://my.vertica.com/docs/ReleaseNotes/7.1.x/HP_Vertica_7.1.x_Release_Notes.htm). I am trying to obtain this hotfix from HP (which only officially offers hotfixes to enterprise customers) and will update this thread if successful.

In the meantime, here is a simpler query that gets at the heart of the problem and can be more easily reproduced:

```
-- query
select
  to_timestamp('2016-03-13 02:38:01', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MI:SS'),
  to_timestamp('2016-03-13 02:38:01', 'yyyy-mm-dd HH:MI:SS')::varchar

-- result obtained in VSQL (CORRECT):
'2016-03-13 02:38:01.0'    '2016-03-13 02:38:01'

-- result obtained via JDBC driver release 7.1.2-0 (INCORRECT):
'2016-03-13 03:38:01.0'    '2016-03-13 02:38:01'
```

Comment: Two questions: (1) do you have the same issue using vsql? (2) which Vertica version?

Comment: @mauro beat me to the `vsql` question. Would like to know that for sure. Also, that docker image is 7.1.1.  There was a bug fixed in the JDBC driver for `timestamptz` but you're saying you aren't using that. If you find `vsql` works, you could try a different jdbc driver.

Comment: (1) Very interesting - the problem does NOT occur in VSQL! So it appears to be a JDBC driver issue? (2) Vertica Community Edition 7.1.1

Comment: I just updated to the latest drivers (vertica-jdbc-7.1.2-0.jar, downloaded from https://my.vertica.com/download/vertica/client-drivers/), and the problem still occurs.

Comment: Well, we're not sure this is a JDBC issue but for sure is on the "client side"